# Unable to Create Listener - Trouble Passing Arguments

Tags: java, android, observable, listener

I'm attempting to create and access a listener in my Observable class from my primary activity using the following:

```
BlePropertyObservable.getInstance().addListener(this, bleIDs)
```

**Observable Class:**

```
public synchronized void addListener(BleEvent listener, BleEventImp eventIds[]) {
    if (null == listener || null == eventIds) return;
    for (BleEventImp id : eventIds) {
        map.put(id, listener);
    }
}
```

**Interface:**

```
public interface BleEvent {

    void updateView(BleEventImp eventId, String action, Object... obj);
}
```

However I'm getting an error stating: *'None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:'* and I'm unsure how I can go about resolving this.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Can you put your Activity code?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/8aQTkwXg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see `BlueToothDriverActivity` doesn't implement `BleEvent` interface. You need to implement it and then you can pass `this` to the `addListener(BleEvent listener, BleEventImp eventIds[])` as `listener`.

Comment: Just to check - you meant like this, correct? 


class BlueToothDriverActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity(), PermissionHelperCallbacks, BleEvent {